# Load data from file storage in xml format and send the parameters to SQL database in logic apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I need to perform below action inside a logic app:

1. Read the data from azure file storage (xml format).
2. Send the data to service bus message queue
3. Read the data from message queue
4. Send the message as a parameter to sql server stored proc.

am able to perform first 3 steps and am not able to send the message from the queue to sql stored proc.

Comment: Could you share a xml sample please? Can you access the file form the logic app ? What is the error you're getting.

Comment: You wan to pass the xml as a parameter of the SP ??? what is the error youre getting

Comment: I am able to read the file from file storage using Get File Content connector and able to send that to Servicebus namespace queue and after that i need to get the message data from queue and send the queue message to Stored proc as a paramater, I am able to read the xml from file storage and send the data to namespace queue and able to read the data from queue but am not able to send the message to stored proc as a parameter.

Comment: why do you need servicebus ? logic app has sql server connector

Comment: i need service bus topic because i have 3 subscriptions for the topic to fetch the messages.and for now am sending complete xml object to sql server and doing the logic in SQL using openXML

Comment: was able to do it using xpath expressions.

Comment: Maybe you should post your answer if you manage to do what you wanted